# Возведение в степень + процент

Tags: java, android, math

Пишу калькулятор на андроид, но не получается сделать функцию процента и возведения в степень (любого числа к любому), так как после нажатия самой кнопки программа сразу считает (присваивает значение второй переменной 0), а должна подождать ввода второй переменной с кнопок (клавиатуры).

Само собой использую метод `Math.pow(a,b)` (для возведения в степень) и кнопка `buttonExponentiation` находится в общем `switch/case`.

Как сделать эту задержку (чтобы кнопка ждала ввод второй переменной)?

```
public void onClick(View view) {

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1:
                ClickNumber(1);
                break;
            case R.id.button2:
                ClickNumber(2);
                break;
            case R.id.button3:
                ClickNumber(3);
                break;
            case R.id.button4:
                ClickNumber(4);
                break;
            case R.id.button5:
                ClickNumber(5);
                break;
            case R.id.button6:
                ClickNumber(6);
                break;
            case R.id.button7:
                ClickNumber(7);
                break;
            case R.id.button8:
                ClickNumber(8);
                break;
            case R.id.button9:
                ClickNumber(9);
                break;
            case R.id.button0:
                ClickNumber(0);
                break;
            case R.id.buttonAdd:
                if (flagAction == 0) flagAction = 1;
                break;
            case R.id.buttonSub:
                if (flagAction == 0) flagAction = 2;
                break;
            case R.id.buttonMult:
                if (flagAction == 0) flagAction = 3;
                break;
            case R.id.buttonDiv:
                if (flagAction == 0) flagAction = 4;
                break;
            case R.id.buttonEq:
                switch (flagAction) {
                    case 1:
                        result = operand1 + operand2;
                        showNumber(result);
                        operand1 = result;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        result = operand1 - operand2;
                        showNumber(result);
                        operand1 = result;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        result = operand1 * operand2;
                        showNumber(result);
                        operand1 = result;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        result = operand1 / operand2;
                        showNumber(result);
                        operand1 = result;
                        break;
                    default:
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Вкажіть дію!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                if (flagAction != 0) {
                    showNumber(result);
                    clearVariables_2();

                }
                break;
            case R.id.buttonClean:
                clearVariables();
                showNumber(operand1);
                break;
            case R.id.buttonComa:


                break;
            case R.id.buttonSquare:
                if (flagAction == 0) {
                    result = Math.pow(operand1, 2);
                    showNumber(result);
     //                    clearVariables_2();
                    operand1 = result;
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.other_operation, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.buttonSqrt:
                if (flagAction == 0) {
                    result = Math.sqrt(operand1);
                    showNumber(result);
                    operand1 = result;
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.other_operation, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.buttonBack:
//                !!!!!!!!!!!!!! NULL     WHY ???????????
                String Temp = null;
                if (flagAction == 0) {
                    if (operand1 % 1 == 0) {
                        Temp = Integer.toString((int) operand1);
                    } else {
                        Temp = Double.toString(operand1);
                    }
                    Temp = Temp.substring(0, Temp.length() - 1);

                    if (Temp.length() > 0) {
                        operand1 = Double.parseDouble(Temp);
                    } else {
                        operand1 = 0;
                    }
                    showNumber(operand1);

                } else {
                    if (flagAction == 0) {
                        if (operand2 % 1 == 0) {
                            Temp = Integer.toString((int) operand2);
                        }
                    } else {
                        Temp = Double.toString(operand2);
                    }
                    Temp = Temp.substring(0, Temp.length() - 1);

                    if (Temp.length() > 0) {
                        operand2 = Double.parseDouble(Temp);
                    } else {
                        operand2 = 0;
                    }
                    showNumber(operand2);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.buttonOff:
                finish();
                break;
            case R.id.buttonExponentiation:
                if (flagAction == 0) {
                    if(operand1 != 0){
//                       some code ..................
                    }
                    result = Math.pow(operand1, operand2);
                    showNumber(result);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.other_operation, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.buttonPercent:
                result = operand1 * 100 / operand2;
                showNumber(result);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Покажите Ваш код.

Comment: case R.id.buttonExponentiation:
                if (flagAction == 0) {
                    if(operand1 != 0){
//                       some code ..................
                    }
                    result = Math.pow(operand1, operand2);
                    showNumber(result);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.other_operation, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;

Comment: Думаю, этого будет мало. И да, не надо добавлять фрагменты кода в комментарий -- добавьте его в сам ответ (и не забудьте про форматирование кода).

Comment: flagAction  - это переменная которая определяет 4 мат. действия operand 1 -это первая переменная operand 2 -это вторая переменная

Comment: так а по какому принципу вы понимаете, что пользователь завершил ввод 2ого числа?

Comment: могу больше, только помогите

Comment: 5 в 4 степени...  сначала нажимаем 5 потом функцию, потом должни ввести сам степень и вывод на екран результата

Comment: вы же в курсе, что настоящие калькуляторы работают по алгоритму [обратной польской нотации](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Обратная_польская_запись)

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно поменять логику возведения в степень (а лучше логику всего калькулятора), например:

```
case R.id.buttonExponentiation:
            if (flagAction == 0) {
//               здесь нужно присвоить какой-либо флаг
                 flag = true;
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.other_operation, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            break;
```

А проверку и сам код возведения перенести на нажатие цифр, внутрь функции     `ClickNumber`

```
.....Код присвоения operand1/operand2.....
......
// проверяете присвоенный вами на прошлом шаге флаг и операнды
if(flag && operand1 != null && operand2 != null){
    // А здесь уже возводите в степень
    result = Math.pow(operand1, operand2);
}
```

Посмотрел в гугл калькулятор и понял о чем вы. Занулять `operand'ы` и флаг вам нужно по нажатию клавиш действия (не цифр).
А `operand2` вам нужно присваивать примерно так:

```
if(operand2 == null){
    operand2 = keyboardval;
} else {
    operand2 *= 10;
    operand2 += keyboardval;
}
```

где `keyboardval` - значение вашей цифры

То есть: вы вводите число, это ваш `operand1`, вводите его до тех пор, пока не была нажата какая-либо клавиша действия, запоминаете `operand1`. После этого запоминаете, какое действие было нажато, присваиваете флаг действия. Если флаг действия был присвоен, то при нажатии цифр, вы уже присваиваете их переменной `operand2` (не забывайте проверять, что `operand1 != null`). Соответственно при каждом нажатии цифры, вы должны пересчитывать значение результата до тех пор, пока снова не будет нажата кнопка действия - в этот самый момент вы выводите результат операции, присваиваете `operand1 = result`, `operand2 = null`.
Для простого калькулятора достаточно этого. Если же вы хотите более сложную версию, как у гугла, то вам придется сохранять все введенные числа и операции, а затем выполнять их по приоритетам.